# use mod_rewrite .htaccess to add www to http:// while removing www from https://

Tags: http, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, firewire

I'd like to use mod_rewite/.htaccess do the following:

- add www to http urls
- remove www from https urls

for the same site

Answer (score 0):

1. Grab the [Apache Mod_Rewrite Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Also http://whathaveyoutried.com.
2. You can check the status of `HTTPS` by using `RewriteCond {%HTTPS} on` (or `!on`)
3. You can check for `www.` on the host using `RewriteCond {%HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$`  (or `!^www\.(.*)$`). The pattern matched is in `%n`, and `RewriteRule` backreferences are `$n`.
4. You can rewrite URLs using `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]`. By switching `http` for `https` and removing the `www.`, you can change this to fit the `HTTPS` rule.

The final code:

```
RewriteCond {%HTTPS} on
RewriteCond {%HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond {%HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond {%HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And I'll say it again, http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: i actually did something similar but it didnt seem to work, turns out something else was breaking .htaccess and have since resolved it. Thanks.

Comment: Should the first RewriteRule specify not https?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've edited my answer to reflect that. Redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP won't work.